# Titanium run command missing when running an iOS test module using SDK 3.3.0.GA

Tags: ios, macos, module, titanium

I'm following [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide) almost to the letter. I can find and run ./build.py and it succeeds. But when I try to run

> titanium run

it's returning:

> [ERROR] "run" is an unrecognized command.

When I get the help, it's missing the run command indeed.

```
Commands:
build     builds a project
clean     removes previous build directories
config    get and set config options
create    creates a new mobile application
help      displays this help screen
info      display development environment information
login     logs into the Appcelerator network
logout    logs out of the Appcelerator network
module    displays installed Titanium modules
plugin    displays installed Titanium CLI plugins
project   get and set tiapp.xml settings
sdk       manages installed Titanium SDKs
setup     sets up the Titanium CLI
status    displays session information
```

I tried to reinstall the titanium cli by running:

> sudo npm install titanium -g

It reinstalled the cli, but still no run command available. What am I missing? 
Any help on this is very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I had missed this: 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Legacy_Command-Line_Interface-section-29004835_LegacyCommand-LineInterface-OSX

When I added the aliasses and opened a new terminal, all is working like the docs.